# Installing spyder 2.7 on windows 7 - 32 bit

Tags: python-2.7

Can anyone please provide the link for downloading spyder 2.7 on windows 7 - 32 bit?

Thanks in advance. Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/)
Windows x86 MSI Installer (2.7.0) (sig) <-- this one

Let me know if this was the thing you looked for.

Comment: After installing that, I am not getting spyder interface. It's only showing python command line. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: To be honest I have no idea. Ill llook in to it now.

Comment: Found another link: http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/Python-spyder-18700-download.aspx maybe this works for you